# find all similar index of array in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a array `X=[1 2 3 1.01 2.01 4 5 1.01 3.01]` I want to all index of this array are similar and difference`<=0.01` in matlab answer is

```
    X1=[1 4 8], X2=[2 5],X3=[3 9],X4=[6],X5=[7]
```

many thanks

Comment: What result would you want for `X = [1.00 1.01 1.02 1.03 1.04]`?

Comment: I think the question is how to find indices of "unique" values where values within 0.01 of each other are considered the same.

Comment: Well, the example in the question could easily be solved with `unique(round(X))`. That's why the OP should clarify (a) whether the tolerance is always around integers and (b) what to do if a sequence of elements are within tolerance of their neighbours but the overall sequence isn't (see my previous comment).

Answer (score 1):

I think the submission ["unique with tolerance" in the FileExchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/27498-unique-with-tolerance) is for you.

You should note, that creating the variables X1...X5 as separate variables is **a bad idea and a bad practice**, because this makes referencing these values in later code (which is either vectorized or loop-based) cumbersome and inefficient. More correct alternatives to storing the data are [`cells`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell.html) (like in the [solution suggested by Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25378212/3372061)) or in [`structs`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/struct.html).

Having said that, if for some reason you still want to create uniquely named variables,  this is possible using a mix of the aforementioned submission (`uniquetol`) and `eval`:

```
[~,b,c]=uniquetol(X,0.01+eps);
for ind1 = 1:length(b)
    eval(sprintf('X%d = (find(c==X(b(%d))))'';',ind1,ind1)); 
end
```

Comment: I think you should change this answer from using `eval` to using a cell array. They OP may ask for individual variables but this is bad practice and should not be promoted.

Comment: I completely agree with you that this is bad practice. I have no idea why the OP wants to do it this way, but this is what was asked for.

Comment: @Dan - answer was amended to include your (justified) remarks.

Answer (score 1):

Here a solution using for-loop. Not sure about efficiency though. Gonna try to find another solution as well.

```
X=[1 2 3 1.01 2.01 4 5 1.01 3.01]
result=cell(length(X),1);
boarder = 0.01;
for n=1:length(X)
    helper = X(n);
    Y=X;
    Y(X>helper+boarder)=0;
    Y(X<helper-boarder)=0;    
    result(n,1)={find(Y)};
end
```

I predefine a cellarray (`result`) which contains all index (for each element of X). Then I loop over the elements setting those who are outside of your boarder to 0. Last but not least I save the index to the result array.

Obviously some results are the same but this way you get also results for the case: `X=[ 1.01, 1.02, 1.03, 1.04,...];`

And if you want to delete those elements which are the same you could loop over your data again and get `unique` results.

Answer (score 1):

```
Y=cell(5,1)
for idx=1:numel(Y)
   Y{idx}=find(abs(X-idx)<=.2);
end
```