# Create a loop using part of variable name in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, loops

I am a beginner in Matlab and have not been able to find an answer to my question so far. Your help will definitely be very much appreciated.

I have 70 matrices (100x100), named SUBJ_1, SUBJ_2 etc. I would like to create a loop so that I would calculate some metrics (i.e. max and min values) for each matrix, and save the output in a 70x2 result matrix (where each row would correspond to the consecutively named SUBJ_ matrix).

I am struggling with both stages - how to use the names of individual variables in a 'for' loop and how to properly save individual outputs in a combined array.

Many thanks and all the best!

Comment: [See related answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25378067/3372061). The `eval(sprintf(...))` is the code/workaround/hack you want, but please note the warning in the beginning (similar to what [Daniel](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25602011/3372061) and [Jonas](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25601997/3372061) mentioned).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As to how to use the names of individual variables in a 'for' loop, here gives an example:

```
SUBJ = [];
for idx = 1:70
    term = eval(['SUBJ_',num2str(idx)]);
    SUBJ = [SUBJ; max(max(term)),min(min(term))];
end
```

Comment: This is what @rochned actually asked for, but as mentioned in the other comments it is not really recommended, e.g. for speed reasons. Whenever you are tempted to use `eval`, there is probably a more efficient way to do things...

Comment: Yeah, I admit that, especially when you have massive data to deal with.

Comment: Thanks, @Highman - this is exactly what I needed! For the current dataset (and other scripts), this seems to work really well. Many thanks also to everyone else for your advice and explanations!

Answer (score 4):

Don't use such variable names, create a big cell array named `SUBJ` and put each Matrix in it.

```
r=zeros(numel(SUBJ),2)
for idx=1:numel(SUBJ)
   r(idx,1)=min(min(SUBJ{idx}))
   r(idx,2)=max(max(SUBJ{idx}))
end
```

`min` and `max` are called twice because first call creates maximum among rows, second call among columns.

Comment: A cell array containing the matrices also works, but I would expect it to be slower than the 3d matrix I give in my solution. It has the advantage though that all 70 matrices do not have to be the same size.

Answer (score 3):

Even though this is in principle possible in Matlab, I would not recommend it: too slow and cumbersome to implement.

You could instead use a 3-D matrix (100x100x70) `SUBJ` which would contain all the `SUBJ_1` etc. in one matrix. This would allow you to calculate min/max etc. with just one line of code. Matlab will take care of the loops internally:

```
OUTPUT(:,1) = min(min(SUBJ,[],1)[],2);
OUTPUT(:,2) = max(max(SUBJ,[],1)[],2);
```

Like this, `OUTPUT(1,1)` contains `min(min(SUBJ(:,:,1)))` and so on...

Comment: A big matrix is even better than a cell array, but your code is not correct. `ALLMINS = min(min(SUBJ,[],1)[],2);` would produce the correct result.

Comment: @Daniel, thanks for that - didn't have MATLAB open and too long since I used it much :-/

Comment: Hi both! Many thanks for your suggestions. While this is practical for this particular (first) task, for a later stage of my data processing, I would still need to somehow create a loop through arrays corresponding to individual subjects. I will need to run sone previously prepared scripts for which the arrays would need to be kept at their original sizes. Would it therefore still be somehow possible to create a loop through individual arrays based on subject names? Thanks!

Comment: To loop through individual subjects you simply loop over the index `ii` in `SUBJ(:,:,ii)`. `SUBJ(:,:,1)` is **identical** to `SUBJ_1(:,:)`; the only difference is notation. The advantage is that it is trivial to increment the index for `SUBJ(:,:,1)` in Matlab, while incrementing the variable name for `SUBJ1(:,:)` is difficult and ugly.