# Identify equivalence classes

Tags: matlab

I want to find something which I think is called equivalent class.
Suppose I have the following matrix:

```
 1     2
 2     3
 4     5
```

which means: 1 is similar to two, two is similar to three and 4 is similar to 5. Essentially, this then means 1,2 and 3 are all similar and 4 and 5 are also similar.

What is the easiest way to figure that out? I.e. get a matrix

```
1 2 3
4 5
```

?

Comment: Careful your argumentation looks like a circle argumentation. Lets say you define an interval of acceptance with `0.2` now you got an array `[ 1.01 1 1.2, 0.98]` they are all inside the interval for the first 2 values. BUT if you compare the last two they are outside of it. Just because 1 resembles 2 and 2 resembles 3 does NOT neccessarily mean 1 resembles 3. Also check out this question: [find all similar indexes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25377876/find-all-similar-index-of-array-in-matalb/25378113#25378113). There is no accepted answers but quite a few good and working answers.